# css for jquery chosen not working in codeigniter

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter, jquery-chosen

I have been trying for multi select dropdown from 5 months!!. Finally found chosen jquery library. I have tried it with all possible combinations and referred over 10 different links. Still css not working.Please help.

Problem specifications:

- I m using codeigniter.
- Downloaded chosen library from https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen
- Included css and js files under projectfolder/chosen/
- I havnt find **chosen.css** file in **Github repository** [Chosen Github repository](https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen) so i copied it from source code of [This Example](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)

Below is my view file

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
    <body>
        <head>
            <title>Add a title</title>
            <!--Css used for chosen dropdown -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>chosen/css/chosen.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>chosen/css/prism.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>chosen/css/style.css">
        </head>
        <body>
          <h1>HELLO DD</h1>
            <select class="chosen-select" tabindex="8" multiple style="width:350px;" data-placeholder="Your Favorite Types of Bear">
                <option value=""></option>
                <option>American Black Bear</option>
                <option>Asiatic Black Bear</option>
                <option>Brown Bear</option>
                <option>Giant Panda</option>
                <option selected>Sloth Bear</option>
                <option disabled>Sun Bear</option>
                <option>Polar Bear</option>
                <option disabled>Spectacled Bear</option>
            </select>

            <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>chosen/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>chosen/js/chosen.jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>chosen/js/prism.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>chosen/js/init.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $(".chosen-select").chosen();
                 });
             </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: press F12 and check your Console to see if there is an error in loading CSS file or not?

Comment: so put the chosen.css as last CSS file.

Comment: @Abbas. Yes your assumption is right. None of them are loading.  What will be solution for this.???

But when i press Ctrl+U and open links. They have code in it.

Comment: try to give the right address for your CSS files. there may be sth wrong in your PHP code.

Comment: Is it necessary to add chosen library under application/library? OR under bootstrap package folder? Or give it permission. ? I m using windows 10. so file permission wont come into picture i guess.

Comment: when you put chosen.css to the end of the list, you override possible CSS classes with the same name in bootstrap and other CSS files. no, it is not necessary as long as you give the correct address for your CSS file.

Comment: I assume you rearranged the files into the folders you specify? They do not seem to have that structure in chosen_v1.8.3.zip

Comment: I have reconfirmed that, i have given correct file path. And my file exists there. Please note that, i havnt loaded bootstrap or any other css/js files apart from chosen library files.

Comment: Probably won't affect the outcome but I recommend using `base_url()` as it was designed to be used. For example use `<?php echo base_url('chosen/js/chosen.jquery.js'); ?>` instead of the concatenation you're using.

Comment: chosen should not be in application/libraries.

Comment: Is the folder "chosen" on the same level as "application"?

Comment: Yes . It is in the same level of application

Comment: `GET http://localhost/Talentub/chosen/css/prism.css net::ERR_ABORTED` error apeared in console once i used `<?php echo base_url('chosen/js/chosen.jquery.js'); ?>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163891/discussion-between-deepamgmg-and-dfriend).